# Formatting headers for aggregated dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:-

```
,issue_name,doc_id,doc_type,doc_title
0,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b519e219b989aaf3db06917,GUIDE,Restart the device
1,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b519e219b989aaf3db06917,GUIDE,Restart the device
2,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b51a24d9b989aaf3db0691a,GUIDE,Fix the App
3,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b51a24d9b989aaf3db0691a,GUIDE,Fix the App
4,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b519e219b989aaf3db06917,GUIDE,Restart the device
5,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b519e219b989aaf3db06917,GUIDE,Restart the device
```

when i am aggregating the same for count with below code:-

```
dfreturns = pd.DataFrame(Guidedocdetails, columns=['issue_name','doc_id','doc_type','doc_title'])
dfreturns.to_csv('ReturnGuideDocDetails.csv')
dfreturnguidecount = dfreturns.groupby(['issue_name','doc_type','doc_title']).agg(['count'])
dfreturnguidecount.to_csv('Return_guideid_counts.csv')
```

i get the output as below:[image]

How do i remove the doc_id and extra lines coming in top. I want output as below:
[image]

Kindly help me understand how can i achieve the same.

After applying below code:-

```
dfnonreturnguidecount = (dfnonreturns.groupby(['issue_name','doc_type','doc_title'])['issue_name'].count().reset_index(name='count'))
dfnonreturnguidecount.to_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv')
```

output:- 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need for remove `MultiIndex` in columns use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
returnguidecount = (dfreturns.groupby(['issue_name','doc_type','doc_title'])
                             .size()
                             .reset_index(name='count'))
```

---

```
returnguidecount = (dfreturns.groupby(['issue_name','doc_type','doc_title'])['issue_name']
                             .count()
                             .reset_index(name='count'))
```

---

```
print (returnguidecount) 
                                      issue_name doc_type           doc_title  \
0  The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging    GUIDE         Fix the App   
1  The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging    GUIDE  Restart the device   

   count  
0      2  
1      4
```

Difference is `count` exclude NaNs values in column specify after `groupby`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But am still getting the extra lines(row 1, column A and column B): am posting the output in my question as can't put it here. any idea how to get rid of these?

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - What return `print (Guidedocdetails.info())` ?

Comment: Guidedocdetails is a list.. dfreturns.info() returns <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 724 entries, 0 to 723
Data columns (total 4 columns):
issue_name    724 non-null object
doc_id        724 non-null object
doc_type      724 non-null object
doc_title     712 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 22.7+ KB
None

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee I test `dfnonreturnguidecount.to_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv')` and there are not numbers in headers, if check file by some text editor like notepd, notepad++ there are numbers in first row?

Comment: there are no numbers in first row when i open it in notepad..there are numbers only in first column(example below). But in csv it is coming as two columns and 1 row.     ,issue_name,doc_id,doc_type,doc_title
0,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b519e219b989aaf3db06917,GUIDE,Restart the device
1,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b519e219b989aaf3db06917,GUIDE,Restart the device
2,The App keeps crashing / restarting / hanging,5b51a24d9b989aaf3db0691a,GUIDE,Fix the App

Comment: hmm, for remove first column use `dfnonreturnguidecount.to_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv', index=False)`

Comment: and first row with numbers you get by `df = pd.read_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv', hedar=None)` ? Because data in csv are correct.

Comment: its not headers, if i do header=None i would not get the columns itself. I am facing this problem whenever i am writing a dataframe to csv. First row and first columns always have numbers. Not sure why.

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - So if use `dfnonreturnguidecount.to_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv', index=False)` still same issue ?

Comment: yes! i have used index=False but its not helping.. The problem is only for csv. In notepad its not coming but csv first row ad columns has numbers

Comment: Ok, how do you test it? By notepad? Or excel? Or something else?

Comment: when i am opening the csv files in pycharm or notepad they donot have the numbers..but my script sends these csv's on mail and when i am opening them in google sheets it has the numbers

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee - So problem has to be in script sending data, not in my solution - it correctly write files. :(

Comment: Yup Might be.. anywayz thank you so much for your time and help!